# Tree field in Drupal

Tags: api, tree, drupal-7

i'm creating a new Module for Drupal 7. The module must modify the content form and add some fields. One of the i'ts a Tree field, i get some taxonomies whith childs from an API and i need to show to the client as Tree like this:

[image]

I'm newbie on Drupal, exists some modules or libs to do that?

Comment: please let me know have you save the child in Drupal taxonomy or fetch direct. if you fetch directly please use custom field for same.

Comment: How about term reference tree module? https://www.drupal.org/project/term_reference_tree